# jQuery set checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I already tried all the possible ways, but I still didn't get it working.
I have a modal window with a `checkbox` I want that when the modal opens, the `checkbox` check or uncheck should be based on a database value. (I have that already working with others form fields.) I started trying to get it checked but it didn't work.

My HTML div:

```html
<div id="fModal" class="modal" >
    ...
    <div class="row-form">
        <div class="span12">
            <span class="top title">Estado</span>

          <input type="checkbox"  id="estado_cat" class="ibtn">
       </div>
    </div>             
</div>
```

and the jQuery:

```js
$("#estado_cat").prop( "checked", true );
```

I also tried with `attr`, and others seen here in the forums, but none seem to work.
Can someone point me the right way?

---

#### EDIT

OK, I'm really missing something here. I can check/uncheck using code if the check box is in the page, but is it's in the *modal* window, I can't. I tried dozens of different ways.

I have a link that's supposed to open the modal:

```html
<a href='#' data-id='".$row['id_cat']."' class='editButton icon-pencil'></a>
```

and jQuery to "listen" the click and execute some operations like filling some text boxes with data coming from database. Everything works like I want but the problem is that I can't set checkbox checked/unchecked using code. Help please!

```js
$(function () {
    $(".editButton").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                id: id,
                op: "edit"
            },
        }).done(function (data) {
            // The next two lines work fine,
            // i.e. it grabs the value from database and fills the textboxes
            $("#nome_categoria").val(data['nome_categoria']);
            $("#descricao_categoria").val(data['descricao_categoria']);

            // Then I tried to set the checkbox checked (because it's unchecked by default)
            // and it does not work
            $("#estado_cat").prop("checked", true);
            $('#fModal').modal('show');
        });

        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: what class is applied on modal div when the modal opens ? Also how do you check the database value - Using AJAX or is it already pre-fetched and stored in a variable ?

Comment: set check box after loading modal window I think you are setting the check box before   loading the modal window.


$('#fModal').modal('show');
$("#estado_cat").attr("checked","checked");

Answer (score 1050):

you have to use the 'prop' function :

```
.prop('checked', true);
```

**Before jQuery 1.6** (see [user2063626's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15044473/1161025)):

```
.attr('checked','checked')
```

Comment: You seem to have the correct answer. Could you elaborate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/29182

Comment: This is good to know. Overlooked this when going through the migration documentation of jQuery 3.3.x

Comment: Good to know that you can not use attr in the newer versions of jQuery as I initially thought

Comment: @Kaloyan I wish I too had known... Could've and would've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This is correct.  After jQuery 1.6, .attr() still has most of the same functionality, but there are a few nuanced situations where it will fail and you need to use .prop() to be 100% covered.

Answer (score 94):

Taking all of the proposed answers and applying them to my situation - trying to check or uncheck a checkbox based on a retrieved value of true (should check the box) or false (should not check the box) - I tried all of the above and found that using **.prop("checked", true)** and **.prop("checked", false**) were the correct solution.

I can't add comments or up answers yet, but I felt this was important enough to add to the conversation.

Here is the longhand code for a fullcalendar modification that says if the retrieved value "allDay" is true, then check the checkbox with ID "even_allday_yn":

```
if (allDay)
{
    $( "#even_allday_yn").prop('checked', true);
}
else
{
    $( "#even_allday_yn").prop('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: Why not just on one single line?  `$(  "#even_allday_yn").prop('checked', allDay);`

Comment: He was trying to demonstrate the possible values. How would you know the real value of the "allDay" without an example like this one here?

Comment: @Xavier Hayoz. This works if, and only if, allDay returns 'true' or 'false' as a litteral value — not a pure binary one. Checkboxes ar badly designed in html and their checked status can be expressed in very different ways. The safe and only one way I know of  is:  allDay === 'true' ? $('#even_allday_yn).prop ("checked", true): $('#even_allday_yn).prop ("checked", false). Notice the strict equality operator.

Comment: `$('#even_allday_yn').prop('checked', allDay === true)` will work because `allDay === true` gives a boolean result.

Answer (score 91):

Try below code :

```
$("div.row-form input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked','checked')
```

OR

```
$("div.row-form #estado_cat").attr("checked","checked");
```

OR

```
$("div.row-form #estado_cat").attr("checked",true);
```

Comment: As in KeyOfJ's answer, use `.prop('checked', true)` instead of `attr` - I just ran into the same issue, and `prop` works.

Comment: FYI if you want to make use of the `:checked` pseudo-selector or other native checkbox HTML features, you must use `.prop`.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work but when I changed the code to  $("div.row-form #estado_cat").prop("checked","checked"); it did work. (Changed attr to prop).

Comment: Unfortunately prop is jQuery 1.6 and higher, so if you are stuck in a legacy framework that won't work for you

Comment: `.attr()` is the way to go for earlier versions, `.prop()` for jQuery 1.6+.

Comment: This worked for me instead of prop. I can see that i was using an earlier version of jquery. .attr() for the win

Answer (score 33):

"checked" attribute 'ticks' the checkbox as soon as it exists. So to check/uncheck a checkbox you have to set/unset the attribute.

For checking the box:

```
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

For unchecking the box:

```
$('#myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

For testing the checked status:

```
if ($('#myCheckbox').is(':checked'))
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 23):

Since you are in a modal window (whether dynamic or in the page) you can use the following code to accomplish your goal: (I ran into the same problem on my site and this is how I fixed it)

HTML:

```
<div class="content-container" style="text-align: right;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="QueryGroupCopyQueries">
    <label for="QueryGroupCopyQueries">Create Copies</label>                                                   
</div>
```

CODE:

```
$.each(queriesToAddToGroup, function (index, query) {
    if (query.groupAddType === queriesGroupAddType.COPY) {

        // USE FIND against your dynamic window and PROP to set the value
        // if you are using JQUERY 1.6 or higher.
        $(kendoWindow).find("input#QueryGroupCopyQueries").prop("checked", true);

        return;
    }
```

In the above "kendoWindow" is my window (mine is dynamic, but I also do this when appending to an element directly in the page). I am looping through an array of data ("queriesToAddToGroup") to see if any rows have an attribute of COPY. If so I want to turn on the checkbox within the window that sets that attribute when a user saves from this window.

Comment: It should be noted that while other answers to the question at hand may "work", using `prop` as this answer suggests is the CORRECT way of accomplishing dynamic jQuery checkbox checking/un-checking.

Answer (score 14):

I know this asks for a Jquery solution, but I just thought I'd point out that it is very easy to toggle this in plain javascript.

```
var element = document.getElementById("estado_cat");
element.checked = true;
```

It will work in all current and future versions.

Comment: I think sometimes we forget some of the more basic things are much better using raw js.

Answer (score 11):

```
.attr("checked",true)
.attr("checked",false)
```

will work.Make sure true and false are not inside quotes.

Comment: Attr won't check the checkbox, prop is the one to do the check. Like `.prop('checked', true);`   [More info in this Post](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/)

Comment: @casivaagustin Depends on the jQuery version.  I believe earlier than jQuery 1.6, `.attr()` did work, as described.

Answer (score 7):

If you're wanting to use this functionality for a GreaseMonkey script to automatically check a checkbox on a page, keep in mind that simply setting the checked property may not trigger the associated action. In that case, "clicking" the checkbox probably will (and set the checked property as well).

```js
$("#id").click()
```

Comment: Because the checkbox has functionality that goes with it, this is the clean way of setting it as checked and let the associated logic run accordingly.  There's a strong case to be made for this to be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

You can write like below given code.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="estado_cat" class="ibtn">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ibtn").click(function(){
        $(".ibtn").attr("checked", "checked");
    });
});
```

Hope it work for you.

Answer (score 5):

```html
<body>
      <input id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" value="false">
</body>

<script>
    $('#IsActive').change(function () {
         var chk = $("#IsActive")
         var IsChecked = chk[0].checked
         if (IsChecked) {
          chk.attr('checked', 'checked')
         } 
         else {
          chk.removeAttr('checked')                            
         }
          chk.attr('value', IsChecked)
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#divParentClip").find("#subclip_checkbox")[0].checked=true;
```

Find will return array , so use [0] to get even if there is only one item

if you don't use find then

```
$("#subclip_checkbox").checked=true;
```

this worked fine in Mozilla Firefox for me

Comment: This works, all other solutions doesn't get detected if you have a :checked style in your css

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me:

```
$checkbok.prop({checked: true});
```

Comment: user   $("#estado_cat").attr("checked","checked");

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running `$("#estado_cat").checkboxradio("refresh")` on your checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
 $("div.row-form input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because you with the newest version of jquery `attr('checked')` returns `'checked'` while `prop('checked')` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem too.

and here is my old doesn't work code

```
if(data.access == 'private'){
     Jbookaccess.removeProp("checked") ; 
    //I also have tried : Jbookaccess.removeAttr("checked") ;
 }else{
    Jbookaccess.prop("checked", true)
}
```

here is my new code which is worked now:

```
if(data.access == 'private'){
     Jbookaccess.prop("checked",false) ;
 }else{
    Jbookaccess.prop("checked", true)
}
```

so,the key point is before it worked ,make sure the checked property does exist and does not been removed.

Comment: Much simplier: `Jbookaccess.prop("checked", data.access != 'private');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this since your are using jQuery UI probably (if not please comment)

```
 $("#fModal" ).dialog({
     open: function( event, ui ) {

     if(//some hidden value check which stores the DB value==expected value for
      checking the Checkbox)

         $("div.row-form input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked','checked');

    }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the check box after loading the modal window. I think you are setting the check box before loading the page.

```
$('#fModal').modal('show');
$("#estado_cat").attr("checked","checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="quiz_answer" id="customSwitch0">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch0"><span class="fa fa-minus fa-lg mt-1"></span></label>
  </div>
```

Remember to increment the the id and for attribute respectively. For Dynamically added bootstrap check box.

```
$(document).on('change', '.custom-switch', function(){
    let parent = $(this);
    parent.find('.custom-control-label > span').remove();
    let current_toggle = parent.find('.custom-control-input').attr('id');
    if($('#'+current_toggle+'').prop("checked") == true){
        parent.find('.custom-control-label').append('<span class="fa fa-check fa-lg mt-1"></span>');
    }
    else if($('#'+current_toggle+'').prop("checked") == false){
        parent.find('.custom-control-label').append('<span class="fa fa-minus fa-lg mt-1"></span>');
    }
})
```