# input checkbox not being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox that in case it's 'checked' it goes as true in the database, otherwise it's false. I want to this result appear with the checked checkbox if its true but it's not working.

CHECKBOX:

```
<span class="new-event-detail"><span><input type="checkbox" id="toCheck" class="addReedemButton" name="addReedemButton" value="true"/>Add Reedem Button</span></span>
```

GETTING DATA FROM DATABASE

```
let hasButton = promotions['add_button']
```

LOGIC:

```
if(hasButton == true){
    console.log('true', eventName)
    $("#toCheck").prop('checked',true)
    $("#toCheck").attr('checked','checked')
}else{
    console.log('false', eventName)
    $("#toCheck").prop('checked',false)
}
```

None of this seems to be working, because I'm getting the result that is true or false but the checkbox is never checked.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630917/1302730

Comment: Your question is unclear please add the working code and explain a little more

Comment: Are you trying to say true false is coming from database? Have you checked what is shown in console with console.log statement?

Comment: Yeah with the console.log I'm getting the name of the div and if they're true or false. Also, I'm using jQuery 3.3.1 but the '.prop('checked', true)' it's not working :/