# Set radio buttons to checked from api response using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

this is the first code i tried and still could not set the radion button to checked

```
$('input:radio[name="reached_cust"]').filter(`[value="${respone.cubiclestate}"]`).attr('checked', true);
```

this is the second code also tried but no success

```
   $("input[name='reached_cust']:checked").val(response.cubiclestate);
```

[api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Jqr.png)

so what i want to achieve is that on edit i want the radio buttons that the user already checked when submitting the form to be checked on edit but currently i get no radio buttons checked on edit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630917/863110

Comment: @Mosh Feu thanks for the tip. you saved my day

Comment: My pleasure :) Goof luck!

Comment: @MoshFeu can you please check this out. I need help with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199157/how-to-get-the-right-value-for-radio-and-checkboxes-to-be-checked-from-api-respo