# How to get the right value for radio and checkboxes to be checked from api response using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Here is my Jquery:

```
   if (response) {
                $("#subterritory").val(response.subterritoyid);
                $("#user").val(response.assignedto);
                $("#startdate").val(response.startdate);
                $('input:checkbox[name="day"]').val(response.inspedays).prop('checked', true);
                 $('input:radio[name="duration"]').val(response.duration).prop('checked', true);
                 $('input:radio[name="repetitive"]').val(response.repetitive).prop('checked', true);

                 bulkId = response.id;

            }
```

First of all I'm getting the radio button and checkboxes to be checked but what is been checked and the response from the Api is different.

I have different radio buttons and checkboxes so I'm using the name attribute to get values but it seems what is been checked and the Api response is different.

Any help on how to get the right radio buttons and checkboxes to be checked correctly is much appreciated.

Here is my html:

```
               <div class="controls">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="monday" name="day" id="monday"  class="custom-control-input" ><span class="custom-control-label">Monday</span> </label>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="tuesday" name="day"id="tuesday" class="custom-control-input" ><span class="custom-control-label">Tuesday</span> </label>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="wednesday"  name="day" id="wednesday" class="custom-control-input" ><span class="custom-control-label">Wednesday</span> </label>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="thursday" name="day" id="thursday" class="custom-control-input" ><span class="custom-control-label">Thursday</span> </label>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="friday" name="day" id="friday" class="custom-control-input"><span class="custom-control-label">Friday</span> </label>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="saturday" name="day" class="custom-control-input"><span class="custom-control-label">Saturday</span> </label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>

 <div class="col-md-4" id="duration">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Duration<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="m-b-10">
                            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input id="status-monthly" name="duration" type="radio" class="custom-control-input"value="monthly">
                                <span class="custom-control-label"  >Monthly</span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input id="status-quaterly" name="duration" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="quaterly">
                                <span class="custom-control-label">Quaterly</span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input id="status-biannually" name="duration" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="biannually">
                                <span class="custom-control-label">Bi-Annually</span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input id="status-annually" name="duration" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="annually">
                                <span class="custom-control-label">Yearly</span>
                            </label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[Api response and ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ab8T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To (un)check a checkbox you don't have to use the `.val()` function who just update (or get) the `value="..."` attribute.

Set query value on the selector instead:

```
// Uncheck all days
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="day"]').prop('checked', false);
// Check only one day
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="day"][value="'+response.inspedays+'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Also i'm not sure that `$('input:checkbox')` is working,   `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` should be better

---

**EDIT:** This is an example is you want to check multiple days:

```js
const days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

// Example :
let response = { inspedays : "monday,wednesday,friday" }

let checked_days = response.inspedays.split(',') // transform string to array
days.forEach(day => {
  let is_day_checked = checked_days.indexOf(day) !== -1 // If day is in array
  $('input[type="checkbox"][name="day"][value="' + day 
 + '"]').prop('checked', is_day_checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="monday" /> Monday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="tuesday" /> Tuesday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="wednesday" /> Wednesday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="thursday" /> Thursday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="friday" /> Friday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="saturday" /> Saturday<br/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="sunday" /> Sunday<br/>
```

**/!\** Please take note that checkbox with same name **isn't a good practice** and should be **unique**. 
You should use something that instead (for monday):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="day-monday" value="1" /> Monday<br/>

$('input[type="checkbox"][name="day- + day + '"]').prop('checked', is_day_checked);
```

Comment: I tried the same for the radio buttons and now I'm getting the right values checked. I want to know how to go about to get  more than one checkboxes (day)checked from the Api response.

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine I updated my answer to add example for multiple check

Comment: i always thought it was only ID's that were supposed to be unique. I never knew about same name. thanks for the advice. I will implement the solution once i get home.

Comment: The ID **must** be unique (because it's the primary usage of it), but input name should be unique on a same form because you can access to all field value from the form tag based on the input's name.