# how to make a checkbox selected from the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, checkbox

how to make a checkbox selected if the data in the database is yes or not, I tried with the attr function but that didn't work

```
 if(data[1].grace == 'yes'){
    console.log('this is yes');
    $("#grace").attr("checked",true);
 }else{
    console.log('this is no');
 }
```

this my html

```
<div class="string-check string-check-bordered-primary mb-2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="grace" class="form-check-input" id="grace">
    <label class="string-check-label" for="grace">
        <span class="ml-2" for="grace"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044340/jquery-set-checkbox-checked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery set checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044340/jquery-set-checkbox-checked)

Comment: No need for jQuery here tough. `document.getElementById('grace').checked = true` If I look at this now, could this be your issue?  You give the string `"true"` and not the boolean `true`

Answer (score -1):

Try to trigger the checkbox instead

```
$("#grace").trigger('click');
```

Comment: Which would cause trouble if there is an event listener on the clicks doing something.

Answer (score -1):

Have you imported jQuery properly? Any error in the console?

https://codepen.io/fuleinist/pen/PowqgRY This is working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grace").attr("checked",true);
});
```