# jQuery Using .each() with .on() for Checkbox's in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so clicking on a table row checks off a checkbox, as well as use localStorage to save the value so when the page is refreshed previously checked box's remain checked.

The code below accomplishes both of these. However, together they cause the checkbox's previously checked (from localStorage) to no longer be toggled by clicking on the row and require you to click directly on the box.

```
<script>

$("tr").each(function(e){
    $("input[type='checkbox']", this).each( function() {
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.value) == 'true') {
            $(this).prop("checked", true)};
    });
});

$("tr").on("click", function(e){
    $("input[type='checkbox']", this).each( function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
        localStorage.setItem(this.value, this.checked);
    });
});

</script>
```

version used: bootstrap-4.5.2, jquery-3.5.1.slim

Comment: try `prop` method instead of `attr` as you did it in `$("tr").each`

Comment: Specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630917/2181514 - you have to use `.prop` for checkboxes in jquery 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).attr('checked')` will always return a string (*see [`.attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)) docs*). So doing a `!` on it will always result in `false` (*unless it was an empty string, but in your code that cannot happen*).

Simplify it to

```
this.checked = !this.checked;
```